# If $f(x) >0$ $\forall x,f(0)=1,f'(0)=-1$ then is $f''(x)>0$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> If $f(x)>0$  $ \forall x$ and  $f(0)=1, f'(0)=-1$
>   then is it true to say $f''(x)>0$ for all values of $x$?

I tried the following example: Let $f(x)=\exp(-x)$, then
$$f(0)=\exp(0)=1,\ \ f'(x)=- \exp(-x) \implies f'(0)=-1.$$
So we find $f''(x)= \exp(-x) > 0$ for all $x$.

So the above statement is true at least for this $f$.

But I don't know whether the statement is true for any $f(x)$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function
$$f(x)=2-\cos(x)-\sin(x) $$
is always positive, and satisfies $f(0)=1,f'(0)=-1$. However, $f''(x) >0$ does not always hold. In other words, your proposition is false.

Comment: Thanks user1337 ;you made my doubt clear ; 
Now i have edited my question as it is being kept as on **hold** ; 
please try to give a comment if you know the answer of my edited question

Comment: @Suresh Please do not edit the question after receiving an answer. That will invalidate the answer. Ask a new question (the answer is yes to your new question) instead of editing this one.

Comment: @JohnMa ....ok ; but i had no choice as it was taking my reputation points